# How to display a custom text on MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am beginner in NSIS, and I want to display the custom text in MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES page as I have two options in Components page 1. Installation and 2. UnInstallation.

So when I choose Below options I am expecting the corresponding text in MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES page.

1. For Installation Option the text should be "Installation completed"
2. For UnInstallation Option the text should be "UnInstallation Completed"

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CompletedText` attribute supports variables:

```
var mycompletedtext
var myfinishsubtext
CompletedText $mycompletedtext

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT "$mycompletedtext"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT "$myfinishsubtext"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section Installer
StrCpy $mycompletedtext "Installation completed"
StrCpy $myfinishsubtext "Something something"
SectionEnd

Section Uninstaller
StrCpy $mycompletedtext "UnInstallation Completed"
StrCpy $myfinishsubtext "Bye bye"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help, 

The text in the CompletedText attribute appearing in the Body of the page.

But I want to change the Header text as well.
1. For Installation option --> Installation Complete
2. For Uninstallation option --> Uninstallation Complete